# Testing an array for an empty string and returning an int (0 or 1) - best practice

Tags: php, arrays

What I started with:

```
foreach($a as $b){if($b=='')return 0;}return 1;  // works but verbose
```

My second attempt:

```
return (in_array('',$a)+0); // returns the opposite of what I need
```

What I am currently using:

```
return in_array('',$a)?'0':'1';
```

using a cast per JRL (shortest)

```
return (int)!in_array('',$a);
```

I assume this is the best way to do this, but just wanted to validate.  Is this the best way to test for an empty value in an array?

I am aware that this tests for 0,NULL,FALSE or an empty string and that is O.K.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you *need* an int and cannot accept a bool?

Comment: @Chris: actually, the shortest is your second attempt, you just need to add the `!`, as in `return !in_array('',$a)+0;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other alternative:

```
return (int)!in_array('', $a));
```

Comment: `(int)!` and `?0:1` are equal in length, but `?0:1` is more efficient than a double type casting (Array-result -> Boolean -> Integer).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a modification of your second statement that should work. Just negate the return value of in_array:

```
return !in_array('',$a);
```

Comment: @Chris: Just cast it to an int.

Comment: *That's not efficient.* First, the `!` casts the function result to a Boolean. Second, `(int)` casts the Boolean to an integer? The if-then-0-else-1 condition check is much more efficient.

Comment: @Rob: Its semantically equivalent and from the point of performance you will never see any significant difference ("Premature optimization is the root of all evil" and so on). Thus I would always choose the cleaner solution, what a full blown `if-then-else` isn't. (However, the ternary operator is also a nice solution)

Answer (score 2):

Your proposal to check an array `$a` for strings cannot be written shorter than:

```
return in_array('', $a)?0:1;
```

If you want to see the difference between 0, NULL, FALSE, or an empty string, add a third parameter to the `in_array` function. This parameter will force the function to also take the type of the element into account. In other words, it compares using `===` instead of `==`.

```
return in_array('', $a, TRUE)?0:1;   //Empty string
return in_array(0, $a, TRUE)?0:1;    //Zero
return in_array(NULL, $a, TRUE)?0:1; //NULL
return in_array(FALSE, $a, TRUE)?0:1;//FALSE
```

See also: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Answer (score 0):

First one isn't correct.

Second one isn't correct

Third one is perfect for your case

OT: Trying to codegolf?

Answer (score 0):

I think as far as best practice goes, just plain `!in_array('', $a)` is the way to go.

There's (generally speaking) no good reason to cast it to an int. Type juggling in PHP works very well. It isn't the PHP way to do casts like this.